# Rock Paper Scissors does not work as expected

Tags: java

I'm doing this Rock, Paper, Scissors Java program for an introduction to programming class and for some reason, the program is automatically terminating after the first user input.

I have a feeling it has to do with the

```
int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(3) + 1;
```

statement but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char userChar;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    // Intro/directions/prompting for user input
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors by Rancid!");
    System.out.println("Choose R for Rock, P for Paper, S for Scissors, or Q to Quit, and press Enter: ");
    userChar = sc.next().charAt(0);

    // Prompting computer to generate a random number
    int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(3) + 1;

    // If computer generates 1 (Rock)
    if (randomNumber == 1) {
        if (userChar == 'r' || userChar == 'R') {
            System.out.println("Rock vs. Rock! It's a tie!");
        } else if (userChar == 'p' || userChar == 'P') {
            System.out.println("Paper covers Rock, you win!");
        } else if (userChar == 's' || userChar == 'S') {
            System.out.println("Rock breaks Scissors, you lose!");
        }

        // If computer generates 2 (Paper)
        if (randomNumber == 2) {
            if (userChar == 'r' || userChar == 'R') {
                System.out.println("Paper covers Rock, you lose!");
            } else if (userChar == 'p' || userChar == 'P') {
                System.out.println("Paper vs. Paper! It's a tie!");
            } else if (userChar == 's' || userChar == 'S') {
                System.out.println("Scissors cuts Paper, you win!");
        }

            // If computer generates 3 (Scissors)
            if (randomNumber == 3) {
                if (userChar == 'r' || userChar == 'R') {
                    System.out.println("Rock breaks Scissors, you win!");
                } else if (userChar == 'p' || userChar == 'P') {
                    System.out.println("Scissors cuts Paper, you lose!");
                } else if (userChar == 's' || userChar == 'S') {
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs. Scissors! It's a tie!");
        }
                // If player chooses to quit
                if (userChar == 'q' || userChar == 'Q') {
                    System.out.println("Player chose to quit. Goodbye!");
                }
                // If player types an invalid character
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input! Please enter a valid character.");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The Java compiler tells you what is wrong. What is the error message you get? Which line does it point to? **Edit:** But the topic of your question and the the body don't match: Does your program not compile? Or does it compile but behave unexpectadly?

Comment: Well mate... your program is doing "all right". Put a breakpoint in the "If (randomNumer == 1).." line and think about.
All your code is in the first if...

Comment: It looks like the curly brackets are off, I think all checks only happen if random number equals 1 which would explain why your program is exiting without doing anything.

Comment: [Strg] + [Shift] + f == Autoformat

Comment: @LutzHorn Well, technically it's compiling, but it's not doing anything. I'm not getting an error message so I know it's not a syntax issue or anything like that. Once it prompts for user input, it's terminating the minute you hit enter regardless of the input.

Comment: If it compiles, then don't say "my program won't compile" as you are doing in the title above. It *does* compile. That is doesn't do what you expected at runtime is something entirely different than "it won't compile".

Comment: All your code is place inside the `if(randomNumber == 1)` block. So since the system pick a number randomly, when it's not 1, it goes directly to the end. You need to take care of your curly braces

Comment: @Patrick was right, my curly brackets were off. Works totally fine now. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Be sure to mark an answer as the solution if it has helped you solve your issue, or if it's not sufficient you can write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

It seems like you're not using any loop inside your main method, so your program simply closes after it executed the last statement.

You want to add something like:

```
while (!"q".equals(userChar) && !"Q".equals(userChar)) {
  System.out.println("Choose R for Rock, P for Paper, S for Scissors, or Q to Quit, and press Enter: ");
  userChar = sc.next().charAt(0);
  // Add your code where you check the randomNumber and the userChar here
}
```

Moreover you want to check your curly braces as the comments already state.

Comment: This is true, but we haven't learned loops in class yet so the program is designed to terminate once complete.